# Apache Rewrite Rule including dynamic directories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, system-administration

I'm trying to create a rule in `.htaccess` using the following conditions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^year=2013$ 
RewriteRule ^/media/news/info.php$ /media/news/month=Month&date=1 [L,R=301]
```

Apparently this rule should work , but it doesn't since `/media/news` are dynamically generated and `apache` doesn't find those directories, and bounces the request to the scripting language who returns a `404`.

My question is how can i "make" `apache` disregard the `validation` for `dynamic directories` and just make the user follow the `RewriteRule` ?

Answer (score 0):

If `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`'s condition match your query, the `RewriteRule` will do the redirection using HTTP 301 and will not check the existence of target.

That means your browser's location should have changed. If it did not change, your `RewriteCond` is not matching your URI or your `RewriteRule`'s condition is not.

If you want Apache to recognize the /media/news/ URL, you need a separate `RewriteRule`, of course.

Comment: I also tested that on localhost. With matching RewriteCond and matching RewriteRule's condition, the redirection did take place even though the target does not exist.

Comment: Your redirection should work on URI /media/news/info.php?year=2013 IMHO.

Comment: Just figured it out! tks anyway for your effort. The Problem has in the RewriteRule the first slash / :

RewriteRule ^/media/news/info.php$

With some help from rewrite log i was able to validate that the RewriteRule did not match because of that initial slash.

Regards